# How to fetch a get request having key value in path variables

Tags: reactjs, get, request, fetch, postman

I am fetching a get request in componentDIdMount function like this-

```
    componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/restaurant/item/findAll/:1')
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data=>{
          console.log(data)
        });
     }
```

But here I have to also pass a key value pair in path variables. For reference please check below image of postman
[image: Postman query image]

Please tell me how to pass key value pair in path variables through fetch request.

Comment: /restaurant/item/findAll?key1=value1&key2=value2

Comment: @UKS Its not working. Please check the image that I have attached for getting the exact idea about what I am asking. Thank you